# Codeigniter input to database with condition

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, crud

i'm newbie of codeigniter i have problem when want add some data using input. In my case, on first page it will get data from user database that show delivery information as default, this input can be edited and if i click submit it will save on delivery database. First problem when i click submit the data, it cant save to database. How to fix this ?. Second case, i want give some condition, if checkbox tick, the data of input will save to user database as default and will save to delivery database.

this My Model(M_checkout) :

```
public function get_user_by_id($customer_id)
{
    $data = $this->db->select('*')
        ->from('user')
        ->where('user_id', $customer_id)
        ->get()
        ->row();
    return $data;
}
public function add_delivery()
{
    $data = array();
    $customer_id = $this->input->post('user_id');
    $this->db->where('user_id', $customer_id);
    $data['user_id'] = $customer_id;
    $data['user_nama'] = $this->input->post('user_nama');
    $data['user_email'] = $this->input->post('user_email');
    $data['user_phone'] = $this->input->post('user_phone');
    $data['user_wa'] = $this->input->post('user_wa');
    $data['user_alamat'] = $this->input->post('user_alamat');
    $data['user_kota'] = $this->input->post('user_kota');
    $data['user_provinsi'] = $this->input->post('user_provinsi');
    $data['user_zip'] = $this->input->post('user_zip');
    $this->db->insert('delivery', $data);
    $customer_deliv_id = $this->db->insert_id();
    $sdata = array();
    $sdata['delivery_id'] = $customer_deliv_id;
    $this->session->set_userdata($sdata);
}
```

this My controller (Checkout):

```
 public function add_delivery_to_db()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_nama', 'Nama', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_email', 'Email', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_phone', 'Nomer Telpon', 'trim|required|min_length[10]|max_length[12]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_wa', 'Nomer WA', 'trim|required|min_length[10]|max_length[12]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_alamat', 'Nomer Alamat', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_kota', 'Nomer Kota', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_provinsi', 'Nomer Provinsi', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_zip', 'Nomer Zip', 'trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[5]');

    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
        $delivery_post_id = $this->M_checkout->add_delivery(); 

        redirect('payment', 'refresh');
    } else {

        redirect('delivery', 'refresh');
    }
}
```

this my view (delivery) :

```
<div class="columns">
    <p>

    </p>
    <div class="column is-3"></div>
    <div class="column is-6 has-addons-fullwidth">
        <form class="" action="<?= base_url() ?>add_deliv" method="POST">
            <section class="mt-2">
                <input class="input is-medium" type="text" placeholder="Nama" name="user_nama" value="<?= $user_info->user_nama ?>" disabled>
            </section>
            <section class="mt-2">
                <input class="input is-medium" type="email" placeholder="Email" name="user_email" value="<?= $user_info->user_email ?>" disabled>
            </section>
            <section class="mt-2">
                <input class="input is-medium" type="text" placeholder="No. Telepon" name="user_phone" value="<?= $user_info->user_phone ?>">
            </section>
            <section class="mt-2">
                <input class="input is-medium" type="text" placeholder="Whatapp" name="user_wa" value="<?= $user_info->user_wa ?>">
            </section>
            <section class="mt-2">
                <input class="input is-medium" type="text" placeholder="Alamat" name="user_alamat" value="<?= $user_info->user_alamat ?>">
            </section>
            <section class="mt-2">
                <input class="input is-medium" type="text" placeholder="Kota" name="user_kota" value="<?= $user_info->user_kota ?>">
            </section>
            <section class="mt-2">
                <input class="input is-medium" type="text" placeholder="Provinsi" name="user_provinsi" value="<?= $user_info->user_provinsi ?>">
            </section>
            <section class="mt-2">
                <input class="input is-medium" type="text" placeholder="Kode Pos" name="user_zip" value="<?= $user_info->user_zip ?>">
            </section>
            <section class="columns mt-4">
                <div class="column">
                    <p class="has-text-white has-text-weight-semibold">
                        Simpan sebagai default
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <input class="checkbox is-white" type="checkbox" name="delivery_checkbox" value="on">
                </div>
            </section>


            <section class="columns">
                <div class="column"></div>
                <div class="column">
                    <button class="button is-danger is-medium">
                        Simpan & Lanjut
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="column"></div>

            </section>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="column is-3"></div>
</div>
```

this my delivery database :[delivery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OD1ju.png)
this my user database :[user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nG1o1.png)

this picture of delivery view [delivery.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y06Q8.png)

Sorry for my bad english. Please help me. I appreciate every answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`INSERT` statements are not supposed to contain a `WHERE` clause. The `where` clause will never be satisfied and thus the insertion will never be made.

A `where` clause would make sense when updating or replacing records (because it would narrow down the **existing** records you actually end up updating)

Remove the `$this->db->where('user_id', $customer_id);` statement from your `add_delivery` method and the insertions will work.

Regarding only making the insert if the checkbox is ticked, there's a lot of choices.
The easiest would be:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
    if ($this->input->post('delivery_checkbox') === 'on')
    {
       // only do the insert if the checkbox is actually ticked
       $delivery_post_id = $this->M_checkout->add_delivery();
    }


    redirect('payment', 'refresh');
}
```